# How to restrict search engines from indexing my mediawiki site?

Tags: seo, mediawiki

Is there a fool proof way to restrict your content from being indexed by major search engines?
Thanks
Prady

Comment: [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)?

Comment: It depends.  Why? What are you trying to prevent?

Answer (score 2):

One *possible* way, is the **[Robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)** file.

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

[Here](http://www.antezeta.com/blog/avoid-search-engine-indexing) is a blog post discussing other techniques, including meta tags.

Comment: Search engines aren't guaranteed to respect this.

Comment: @SLaks - true, but AFAIK there is no real way to *guarantee* this (answer updated). Do you know a sure fire way?

Comment: thats right... Search engines dont respect robot.txt all the time.

Comment: @SLaks - What do you mean? make *all* pages on your site secure?

Comment: @SLaks : Would making the site pwd protected restrict searchengine?

Comment: @Prady Yes, unless they knew your password and were logging in. That is unlikely :)

Comment: Yeah i guess you could make all your pages secure, but that kind of seems like a design decision for the application/domain, not to scare away search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Most search engines follow `robots.txt`. I've heard Yahoo Slurp! does not.

You could scan user agent for well known bots, such as Google, Yahoo, Bing, Internet Archive, etc and produce blank output. You will be penalised for giving alternate content to Google, but since you are blocking them, it won't be a problem.

The most important thing is whatever you publish publically can and will be accessed by bots such as search engine spiders.

Don't forget bots have a [nasty habit of being where you don't want them to be](http://ww.thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx) (mixed with bad coding practices, can be quite disastrous).

Answer (score 0):

Fool proof? I think not. You can restrict IP's, use Robots.txt, meta tags, but if a search engine really really wants your content indexed, it will find a way.

Comment: Passwords​​​​​​?  Smart cards?

Comment: @SLaks I guess it depends on what "content" he is referring to. If he is talking about his site in general, even passwords can't prevent indexing.

Comment: @Slaks - instead of adding lots of comments to this question and other answers, perhaps it would make more sense to post an answer?

Comment: @RPM: Smart cards or password protection probably aren't what he's looking for.